# Multithreading python code stops working until a process is terminated

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

the code works syntactically and well with a core. But I have to edit more than 15,000 files, that's why I decided to multithreading.

With a PC with 6 processors and 8 GB of RAM, I get up to 2,000 files. Then the code stops working. Attention: There is no error message. It just does not work anymore. After I finish a process over the task manager (python 3.6) it runs again. After about 100 iterations it stops again. When I finish a process after that, it keeps going.

I have tried the code on my Mac, the same thing happens there with 1,200 files.
My Pool concept:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(4)
    p.map(parseAndSave, glob.glob(PATH_XML+"*.xml"))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

The whole Code is here: https://pastebin.com/7tKvt5Jd

How can I find the problem?

Comment: It really depends on what are you doing in that function. Do you close the file you open? Try to create a minimal example so that one could try and reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have check it out, there are no open files and so on. The code works also good on 1 or more files.

Comment: Usually this behaviour is caused by some kind of limit reached by the processes. It could be an open request limit, a open file limit, some wait/join got out of hand, there are really many possible reasons. The best procedure I could suggest you to find the culprit is to try and explore the code dichotomously, by deleting the code until this symptom disappears. If still you'll have not figure the error out, you'll have created a minimum example and we could help you out from there.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of have a hunch that your problem could be selenium related. It does not work that well in a multiprocessing environment (you actually create subprocesses, not threads here).

As you seem to be only interested in getting the page source in its entirety and not interacting with the page in any way, it might be safer, and definitely significantly faster and more reliable, to use `urllib.request.urlopen()` to retrieve this.